# Design custom view in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, xcode8

This is my first time working with custom view and I'm so confused as to how to proceed.

I have a custom view, inherited from `NSView` with just 3 things on it: an image view, and 2 text fields:

```
// MyCustomView.swift
import Cocoa

@IBDesignable class MyCustomView: NSView {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleField: NSTextField!

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

I added a XIB file, designed the view and connected all the outlets:

[image: MyCustomView.xib]

Now my main storyboard I added a generic view, change its class to `MyCustomView` and connected the outlet. Here's the code for `ViewController.swift`:

```
// ViewController.swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: MyCustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView.titleField.stringValue = "This is a title"
    }
}
```

At run time I got a fatal error on the `customeView.titleField.stringValue = ...` line:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

If I take out that line, the app compiles but the custom view is blank.

So I guess my custom design did not carry over from `MyCustomView.xib`? How can I correct that? I double checked and all the outlets are connected in IB.

Comment: Why do you need to subclass NSView when in fact you can access those controls by wiring them with the view controller?

Comment: The actual custom view is more complex. This is a simplified example

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. i know what the error means but I'm asking how to set up my view and Interface Builder to avoid the error.

Comment: Have you checked that neither `customView` nor `customView.titleField` is `nil`?

Comment: Did you consider the IB lifecycle? I mean, have you tried to put your code in awakeFromNib or something like that? This really seems like a lifecycle issue, probably because the IBOutlet is not instantiated yet, since it is optional and you're using forced unwrap...

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your class in the Identity Inspector for the UIView `MyCustomView`?
2. Is the `IBOutlet` link set correctly as a `MyCustomView`? (your storyboard side)
3. Is the file owner for the XIB set to `MyCustomView`?
4. Do you have initialisers for `MyCustomView`? ( override init(frame: CGRect) or required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) )